# Count values that are grouped by beginvalue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a column named "StatusCode". In there are all the statuscodes from a website. I want to group all the statuscodes with the same begin-value, and count them together. [See this page with all the status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The value's in the database are like this:

```
+--Id--++--Systemlogid--+--StatusCode--+-Count-+
|  1   |      1         |    404       |  200  |
|  2   |      1         |    403       |  200  | // values in the database
|  3   |      1         |    500       |  300  |
|  4   |      1         |    501       |  300  |
+------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

The values's in the Count part are ment to be the sum of all the values with the same statuscode-begin.

**As you have seen above my database contains:**

```
| 1 | 1 | 404 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 403 | 200 |
```

When I count them together, all the statuscodes with a 4 in the begin I get the value 400 (200 + 200)

**My database contians these values too:**

```
| 1 | 1 | 500 | 300 |
| 2 | 1 | 501 | 300 |
```

When I count these together, all the statuscodes with a 5 in the begin I get the value 600 (300 + 300)

**What gives the table:**

```
+--StatusCode--+-Count-+
|    4xx       |  400  |
|    5xx       |  600  |
+--------------+-------+
```

So: 1xx are all statuscode's that begin with 1. 2xx are all the statuscode's that begin with 2. 3xx are all statuscode's that begin with 3 etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast and group...

```
select left(cast(statuscode as varchar(3)),1) + 'xx' as StatCode, 
       sum([Count]) as Counted
from Table1
group by left(cast(statuscode as varchar(3)),1) + 'xx'
```

Comment: I have more collums that those 2. Now it is getting a other value out of a other column (Id).

Comment: @jarlh that are the 2 colums you will only need. But i will add the other one's in my example.

Comment: @M.Arendsen, when you do GROUP BY other columns make a huge difference...

Comment: @M.Arendsen Based on your sample data and expected output, this is the query you need. If it doesn't meet your needs, refine your question.

Comment: @M.Arendsen Yeh, I'm going to ignore the other columns, they are not required int he output so should not appear int he code. I have changed count() to sum() to sum up your `Count` column

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @newtable TABLE
( id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
value INT )

    INSERT INTO @newtable VALUES(1000),(2231),(2112),(2007),
(3002),(3001),(4322),(4321),(4326),(4327),(43299)

SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,value),1,1)+'xx' AS 'StatusCode',
COUNT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,value),1,1)) AS 'Count'
    FROM @newtable GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,value),1,1)
```

You can directly run this query to check, as i have used a dynamic table to achieve what you require as an example, and you can modify your query accordingly, then.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer, I dont need to count every time there is a value that begins with "x". I need to count the value that is behind the statuscode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a scalar-valued function like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCountOfstatus]
(
    @StatusCode NVARCHAR(3) 
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res int
    SET @res = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE LEFT(cast(StatusCode AS NVARCHAR(3)) , 1) = LEFT(@StatusCode,1) )
    RETURN @res
END
```

after creating function you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * , 
        LEFT(StatusCode,1) +'XX' AS Code ,  
        [dbo].[GetCountOfstatus](StatusCode) AS CodeCount  
FROM TABLE1
```

just replace your table name

Comment: It was a "." instead of "," . Try again please.

Comment: you should run only first part of code from "create function "  to " end " .

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer I am looking for. This gives the same (but than worse) result as the aswer from @Dheeraj Sharma